# Using GitHub authentication to see private repositories without using GitHub API

Tags: python, github, github-api

I have used GitHub API to access private repositories using the `Authorization` header. This works very well. But, I am unable to see the the repository i.e. send a GET request for the repository webpage.

Suppose the url I want to access is

```
url = 'https://github.com/username/repo'
```

which is the link to my private repository. And I have

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'token mygithubtoken'}
auth = {'myusername', 'mypassword')
```

I am sending a get request as following

```
>>> res = requests.get(url, auth=auth, headers=headers)

>>> print(res.status_code)
404
```

I want to do this because the diff of a pull request is also not accessible this way which is located at `https://github.com/user/repo/pull/pr_no.diff`

Answer (score 2):

I contacted GitHub support and they answered it. We can't use OAuth tokens to access the website. However, diffs are available through the API:

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request

you can pass in the `application/vnd.github.VERSION.diff` media type to get the diff. So that would make my

```
url = https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number
```

and

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token mygithubtoken',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.VERSION.diff',
}
```

Thanks GitHub support for this !